# One if condition works perfectly in laravel blade but another doesn't work

Tags: laravel, if-statement, conditional-statements, laravel-blade

I have some problem in laravel blade i have simple table and first if condition works perfectly but second doesn't work maybe some one can say where is my mistake because condition almost similar to first if ;/

```html
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Naujausi knygų išdavimai</h4>
<div class="pagrindinis">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead class="bg-warning">
            <th>Knygos pavadinimas</th>
            <th>Miestas</th>
            <th>Išdavimo data</th>
            <th>Grąžinimo terminas</th>
            <th>Vardas</th>
            <th>Pavardė</th>
            <th>Kliento nr.</th>
            <th>Veiksmai</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($paskolinimai as $p)
            <input type="hidden"
                value="{{ $skirtumas =  \Carbon\Carbon::parse(\Carbon\Carbon::today()->toDateString())->diffInDays( \Carbon\Carbon::parse( $p->terminas),false) }}">
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $p->pavadinimas }}</td>
                <td>{{ $p->miestas }}</td>
                <td>{{ $p->isdavimo_data }}</td>
            @if($p->grazinimo_data != NULL)
                <td>
                    <strong style="color: green;">Knyga grąžinta!</strong>
                </td>
            @elseif($skirtumas > 0)
                <td>
                    Liko <strong style="color: crimson;">{{ $skirtumas }}</strong> dienų.
                </td>
            @elseif($skirtumas < 0)
                <td>
                    <strong style="color: crimson;">Terminas praėjo!</strong>
                </td>
            @elseif($skirtumas = 0)
                <td>
                        <strong style="color: crimson;">Šiandien paskutinė grąžinimo diena!</strong>
                </td>
            @endif
                <td>{{ $p->vardas }}</td>
                <td>{{ $p->pavarde }}</td>          
                <td>{{ $p->klientasnr }}</td>
            @if($p->grazinimo_data = null)  
                <td><a href="{{ url('patvirtinti-grazinima-'.$p->id.'-'.$p->bookid) }}"
                            class="btn btn-primary">Grąžinimas</a> </td>
            @elseif($p->grazinimo_data != null)
                <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Grąžinta</a> </td>
            @endif  
            @endforeach
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning the property

Change

`$p->grazinimo_data = null`

to

`$p->grazinimo_data === null`

or

`is_null($p->grazinimo_data)`

Comment: Thanks mate it works but why first if with only one = works?

Comment: "!=" is an comparison operator (not equal) and "=" is an assigment operator (setting a value)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php